# Systemd weirdness: Cannot add dependency, file exists

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a Debian armel machine running wheezy, upgraded to Debian Testing today. As you can guess from the title, systemd is weird in two ways:

1) On boot, a swath of errors "Cannot add dependency X to Y.target, ignoring: File exists" appears, however the system appears to boot normally. The errors are:

```
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency -.mount to local-fs.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-journald.service to sysinit.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency udev.service to basic.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-journald-dev-log.socket to sockets.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency udev-control.socket to sockets.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency udev-kernel.socket to sockets.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-journald.socket to sockets.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-journald-audit.socket to sockets.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service to graphical.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rsyslog.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency remote-fs.target to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency dbus.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-user-sessions.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency org.freedesktop.login1.busname to busnames.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rsyslog.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency ssh.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency remote-fs.target to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency cron.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rc-local.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency dbus.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-user-sessions.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-ask-password-wall.path to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-logind.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency getty.target to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rsyslog.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency ssh.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency remote-fs.target to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency cron.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rc-local.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency dbus.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-user-sessions.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-ask-password-wall.path to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-logind.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency getty.target to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
Oct 20 17:19:42 gw-16b1 systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service to rescue.target, ignoring: File exists
```

2) watchdog is not started any more by default, which causes the HW watchdog, initialized by a bootloader I won't flash without JTAG access, to reset the system. Attempting to enable it with ´systemctl -f enable watchdog` yields this error:

```
Synchronizing state of watchdog.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable watchdog
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5 S) of script `watchdog' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
[ 3269.248986] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency cron.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
[ 3269.279002] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-user-sessions.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
[ 3269.309118] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency getty.target to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
insserv: warning: current start runlevel(s) (2 3 4 5 S) of script `watchdog' overrides LSB defaults (2 3 4 5).
[ 3273.549003] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rc-local.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
[ 3273.579012] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-ask-password-wall.path to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
[ 3276.708974] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency rc-local.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
[ 3276.738972] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-ask-password-wall.path to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
[ 3276.768990] systemd[1]: Cannot add dependency systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service to multi-user.target, ignoring: File exists
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

3) Apparently something with the RTC is weird, too, because since the upgrade the process `root         1 22.3  1.2   6372  3184 ?        Ss   18:16   0:15 /sbin/init fixrtc` stays launched, despite both RTC and ntpdate working properly.

How do I get rid of all the systemd warnings and make watchdog auto start? A simple `service watchdog start` works fine, so it is definitely a systemd problem.

Answer (score 0):

It means the systemd service files for all of listed tools/packages are missing. You need to find toolname.service file and place it into /lib/systemd/system.

In poor words, your systemd service commands are not going to work for the tools that the systems warns during the boot. I suggest you to backup your data and perform a clean install since upgrade messed up.

Comment: Nope, the files exist (e.g. `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 251 May 14 09:44 /lib/systemd/system/cron.service`)...

Comment: yes, the files are there but they are symlinked, as your logs suggest as well sysmlinks may be messed. That is why I said you need to find them and place them correctly. Doing a distro upgrade from stable to testing is never been recommended so I am not surprised at all that this happened. you should be aware of the risks. Go for clean install.